# SQL Server join on result of aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2017

SQL Server 2017.
I have 2 tables, with hacker name and id, and another coding challenges submitted by each (below).  I need to output id, name and count of challenges, filtering out those hackers who submitted the same number of challenges, except when this number is a maximum.
Here is sample data and final output i need

Hackers:

```
hacker_id name
1 john
2 tom
3 anna
4 mary
5 steve
```

Challenges:

```
challenge_id    hacker_id
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   2
6   2
7   2
8   3
9   3
10  3
11  4
12  4
13  4
14  4
15  5
16  5
```

this is the count of challenges per person (from here, we see that max number is 4 per person) :

```
hacker_id   name    count of challenges
1   john    3
2   tom     4
3   anna    3
4   mary    4
5   steve   2
```

The final output would be as follows:

```
hacker_id   name    count of challenges
2   tom     4
4   mary    4
5   steve   2
```

i.e. tom and mary both submitted 4 challenges. They are included because although the number 4 repeats, it's a maximum
John and Anna submitted 3 each. They are excluded because 3  is not a max per person. Steve submitted 2 and this number is unique, so he's included, too.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT h.hacker_id, 
h.name, 
COUNT(c.challenge_id) AS ChalCountPerHead
FROM    hackers h 
        JOIN challenges c ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
        LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT d.FreqHacker, COUNT(d.FreqHacker) as FreqOfFreq FROM 
                (SELECT hacker_id, COUNT(challenge_id) AS FreqHacker 
                 FROM Challenges GROUP BY hacker_id) d
            GROUP BY d.FreqHacker
        ) dd
        ON FreqHacker = COUNT(c.challenge_id)
GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name
HAVING 
COUNT(c.challenge_id) = (SELECT MAX(d.FreqHacker) from d) 
OR
dd.FreqOfFreq = 1
```

It doesn't work, stating an error message on this line

```
ON FreqHacker = COUNT(c.challenge_id)
```

> An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a sub query contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: You'll need to use a subquery or CTE to do the aggregation, and then you can `JOIN` on the derived column.

Comment: Also `COUNT(c.challenge_id) = (SELECT MAX(d.FreqHacker) from d)` won't work; as `d` is the alias subquery in a subquery in the query. You have to reference an actual object.

Comment: @Larnu, I am new to sql, not sure how to do that. any tweaks to this code that might work? or maybe you can help adjust this code with CTE ? i have been trying to solve it for so many hours now that my head is one big mess, that is why I came asking for help :(

Comment: I could take a guess, yes, but i wouldn't be able to test it. It would really help if you provided us with some **consumable** sample data and the expected results you're after.

Comment: @Larnu, I am editing the question to include sample tables and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

Having sample data in the question make it way easier to verify the solution. Please include it next time.

`CTE` is a simple aggregation to get the number of challenges submitted by each hacker.

In `CTE2` `MAX` gives the global maximum frequency. `HackerCountOfSameFreq` is the count of hackers that have the same frequency.

Final `WHERE` removes groups of hackers that consist of more than 1 hacker, but leaves the group that has the maximum frequency.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @Hackers TABLE (hacker_id int, name varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @Hackers VALUES
(1, 'john'),
(2, 'tom'),
(3, 'anna'),
(4, 'mary'),
(5, 'steve');

DECLARE @Challenges TABLE (challenge_id int, hacker_id int);
INSERT INTO @Challenges VALUES
(1 ,  1),
(2 ,  1),
(3 ,  1),
(4 ,  2),
(5 ,  2),
(6 ,  2),
(7 ,  2),
(8 ,  3),
(9 ,  3),
(10,  3),
(11,  4),
(12,  4),
(13,  4),
(14,  4),
(15,  5),
(16,  5);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT hacker_id, COUNT(*) AS FreqHacker
    FROM @Challenges
    GROUP BY hacker_id
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT
        hacker_id
        ,FreqHacker
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FreqHacker) AS HackerCountOfSameFreq
        ,MAX(FreqHacker) OVER () AS GlobalMaxFreq
    FROM CTE
)

SELECT
    CTE2.hacker_id
    ,CTE2.FreqHacker
    ,H.Name
FROM
    CTE2
    INNER JOIN @Hackers AS H ON H.hacker_id = CTE2.hacker_id
WHERE
    HackerCountOfSameFreq = 1
    OR FreqHacker = GlobalMaxFreq
ORDER BY
    CTE2.hacker_id
;
```

**Result**

```
+-----------+------------+-------+
| hacker_id | FreqHacker | Name  |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| 2         | 4          | tom   |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| 4         | 4          | mary  |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| 5         | 2          | steve |
+-----------+------------+-------+
```

---

Your query also produces correct result (at least with this sample data), once the syntax is fixed.

I've split it into CTEs, leaving most of your logic as is:

```
WITH
d
AS
(
    SELECT hacker_id, COUNT(challenge_id) AS FreqHacker 
    FROM @Challenges 
    GROUP BY hacker_id
)
,dd
AS
(
    SELECT d.FreqHacker, COUNT(d.FreqHacker) as FreqOfFreq 
    FROM d
    GROUP BY d.FreqHacker
)
,d3
AS
(
    SELECT 
        h.hacker_id, 
        h.name, 
        COUNT(c.challenge_id) AS ChalCountPerHead
    FROM    
        @hackers h 
        JOIN @challenges c ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
    GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name
)
,d4
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        d3
        LEFT JOIN dd ON dd.FreqHacker = ChalCountPerHead
)
SELECT *
FROM d4
WHERE
    ChalCountPerHead = (SELECT MAX(d.FreqHacker) from d)
    OR FreqOfFreq = 1
ORDER BY hacker_id
;
```

Comment: HI Vladimir, i have just added sample data into the question. i'll test your solution now, thank you for this.

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot, now i'll go and learn what you did there )) once again thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess, you can get the same result without window functions (that use `OVER()` clause). In any case, start using CTEs instead of subqueries and you'll see how much more readable the query becomes.

Comment: that is very true, although i don't yet know the partition bit, i can ready the code easily and there is no confusion as to where comes what, very neat and tidy. Much appreciated!

Comment: @LanaB, I updated the answer, you can see how your original query looks like if it is written using CTEs instead of subqueries. In the final `SELECT` your `HAVING` becomes simple `WHERE`.

Comment: Vladimir, you mentioned that my code works if syntax errors are fixed. not sure if i can ask this, but where were the errors? just for my knowledge.

Comment: @LanaB, you just can't write `ON FreqHacker = COUNT(c.challenge_id)`. SQL doesn't support such expressions. And then you reference `d` second time in a way that is not supported. All these are good candidates for CTE. I don't know off the top of my head how to write this query without using CTEs. Maybe it is possible, most likely you'll have to repeat parts of the query and overall it will be much harder to read.

Comment: okay, let's leave it there then. I've learnt a great deal from your answer already, thank you.